# Using Catchall email id to create ticket

Tags: email, smtp, webhooks, web-development-server, catch-all

I am creating an application that has set of users ( roughly 5000 and growing ). External companies can send them certain documents by email. I dont want to create so many email ids and what to use a catchall email id.

This catchall email will capture the email and forward it to an API / Webhook, based on unique id,  (eg. email id can be someuniqueid@mydomainname.com or someotheruniqueid@mydomainname.com )

The API will store the documents against the specific user who can be identified by unique id in the email.

With this, I don't need to create email ids for each user.

Can this be achieved by setting up own SMTP or I can use some third party?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a different architecture?

1. External company sends an email to user with attachments.
2. User extracts email attachments.
3. User logs in to your system with user unique id.
4. User creates a project and uploads attachments to server.

If your goal is to automate the parsing and user assignment of emails, you're in for a treat.